# SQL query to remove multiple duplicate entries from table

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

I have table containing following entries

```
Id  |   Accno  |    Name   |    Hash
----+----------+-----------+---------
 1  |    11    |     ABC   |    01110
 2  |    11    |     ABC   |        
 3  |    22    |     PQT   |        
 4  |    33    |     XYZ   |    03330
 5  |    44    |     LMN   |    04440
 6  |    33    |     XYZ   |
```

I need SQL query to remove duplicate entry from table and keep atleast single entry in table whose hash value is present. and for those entries which are not duplicate should also remain in table.

Comment: Please be more specific in what you want, provide us with example

Comment: Which columns should it be checking for duplicates? `Accno`, `Name`, or both together?

Comment: Write a `SELECT` query that returns all the rows you want to keep. Then use `DELETE FROM YourTable WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM (<subquery>))`, where `<subquery>` is the query you wrote.

Comment: Can you give expected output of given data so we can clarify what you want?

Comment: I want output as Id  |   Accno  |    Name   |    Hash
----+----------+-----------+---------
 1  |    11    |     ABC   |    01110
 3  |    22    |     PQT   |        
 4  |    33    |     XYZ   |    03330
 5  |    44    |     LMN   |    04440

Answer (score 1):

I think you guys overcomplicate things a lot. This should work just dandy:

```
DELETE FROM 
    YourTable
WHERE Hash IS NULL
AND Accno IN 
    (
    SELECT Accno
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY Accno
    HAVING COUNT(Name) > 1
    )
;
```

Comment: Thanks [Dagg Nabbit](http://stackoverflow.com/users/886931/dagg-nabbit) for the suggested corrections.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to do it is to create a new table and copy non duplicate entries.

```
create table table_name2 as select distinct * from table_name1;
drop table table_name1;
rename table_name2 to table_name1;
```

Something like this.

Comment: This will copy all the rows, because the `id` column makes them all distinct. He also said he wants to keep the row with a non-empty `Hash` column.

Comment: I want to remove duplicate entries of accno and keep those entries for which hash is present and in case hash is not present for any unique entry keep that too in database

Answer (score 0):

```
Create table temp2 as SELECT *
FROM temp where id in (select id from temp group by accno having count(accno)>=1 and hash<>'');    
drop table old_table;
rename table temp2 to old_table;
```

Check [<kbd>**SQL Fiddle**</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c768e8/1)